# Google Reader API Listing feed from a single tag or category

Tags: python, google-reader, calibre

I'm writing  a python script (in fact a Calibre Recipe) to retrieve all the items under a specific tag or category in my readlist.
I'm able to retrieve the whole items from the category but I'ld like to retrieve items feed-by-feed, so I need a way to list the feeds filed under a specific category (just as Google Reader UI does when you click on a folder).
I'm unable to find a API for doing that.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription/list` to list the user's subscriptions. The folders each subscription is in are given by the `categories` list. You can append `?output=json` to get the list of subscriptions as JSON.